# Why can't I test my project using JUnit 4?

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I am using Spring 3, Hibernate 3 in my project. But I can not test it using JUnit 4.

Here is my Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:WebRoot/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"})
public class UserDaoTestCase extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void testSimple() {
        // do some tests...
    }



    // setters and getters
    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

}
```

I run this test, and I always get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL
>   [file:WebRoot/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to
>   get the default Bean Validation factory   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:127)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1704)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1654)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
>     ... 37 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:118)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to
>   build the default ValidatorFactory    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:383)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)
>     ... 50 more Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable
>   to instantiate Configuration.     at
>   javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:272)
>     at
>   javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:380)
>     ... 51 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:960)   at
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.loadBundle(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:202)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.getFileBasedResourceBundle(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:182)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.(ConfigurationImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:43)
>     at
>   javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
>     ... 53 more

My IDE is MyEclipse 9, and I am using JavaEE 6 libraries.

I think my applicationContext.xml is fine, 'cuz it works fine when I run this project in tomcat, no exceptions.

Here is my SessionFactory bean in applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="c3p0DataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.myproject.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
             <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">
                 org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
              </prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
       </props> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

How can I do tests using JUnit 4 correctly?

Comment: Likely because you're not executing the tests from the directory you think you are.

Answer (score 6):

I expect you've got the path to the **application-context.xml** wrong, as Spring sees it. I'd first try dropping off **WebRoot/**.

I'd attach the Spring sources to my project and hook-up a debugger, breaking on line:

> org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)

In there, you'll see where it's loading the application context and you can use an interactive expression executer to try multiple different strings to figure out what it can and can't see.

I'd also try this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext*.xml" })
```

That work's in my project where the files are in **WEB-INF/classes** in the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really use your production applicaton context for tests?

I would change the approach to use a different application context for tests (e.g. for defining test data sources and stuff) and place it along with your other test resources. Then a simple lookup as the following one will do.

```
@ContextConfiguration("/path/to/my/test-context.xml")
```

In your example, you have to make sure the path is correct! Your file URL should be translated to a folder relative to your project's root folder. Does the application context lie there?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:WebRoot/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"})
```

I think you do not locate your Spring context configuration file from file:// . re-locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, in my case the problem was with the application context xml configuration file being loaded. It was not a properly defined application context. To be precise,  "xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" namespace was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I too have same problem, When I updated both src/test/resources/ApplicationResource.properties and src/main/resources/ApplicationResource.proerties.

And I updated, POM.xml with context and test dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The src/test/resources/ApplicationContext.xml loaded successfully.

My problem got solved.